# inline-block блок не по размеру уходит вниз

Tags: html, css, display, inline-block

Кто нибудь, объясните почему левый блок уходит вниз и как его поднять?!

```html
    <div style="width: 15%; min-height: 100%; display: inline-block; ">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae aut laborum enim ad dolorem vel delectus quasi voluptates! Incidunt, eum itaque. Laboriosam aut ab deserunt a sit, itaque saepe deleniti!
    </div>
    <div style="width: 15%; min-height: 100%; display: inline-block; ">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non ipsam alias, eos exercitationem nesciunt pariatur. Sunt libero pariatur enim impedit amet, soluta eaque provident ex eum unde dolore praesentium deserunt?
      Unde neque earum inventore, doloribus, similique autem dicta tempore aliquam recusandae asperiores cupiditate tempora rem. Veritatis repellat veniam, sequi blanditiis dolores, eaque quaerat architecto quidem recusandae dolor non sint nesciunt.
      Saepe hic omnis et iure recusandae labore doloribus molestiae reiciendis sapiente facere delectus accusamus aliquam unde voluptatem distinctio nihil, rem, impedit eveniet ea harum sit! Provident similique ducimus fugit possimus.
    </div>
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно задать вертикальное выравнивание `vertical-align: top`

```html
    <div style="width: 15%; min-height: 100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae aut laborum enim ad dolorem vel delectus quasi voluptates! Incidunt, eum itaque. Laboriosam aut ab deserunt a sit, itaque saepe deleniti!
    </div>
    <div style="width: 15%; min-height: 100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non ipsam alias, eos exercitationem nesciunt pariatur. Sunt libero pariatur enim impedit amet, soluta eaque provident ex eum unde dolore praesentium deserunt?
      Unde neque earum inventore, doloribus, similique autem dicta tempore aliquam recusandae asperiores cupiditate tempora rem. Veritatis repellat veniam, sequi blanditiis dolores, eaque quaerat architecto quidem recusandae dolor non sint nesciunt.
      Saepe hic omnis et iure recusandae labore doloribus molestiae reiciendis sapiente facere delectus accusamus aliquam unde voluptatem distinctio nihil, rem, impedit eveniet ea harum sit! Provident similique ducimus fugit possimus.
    </div>
```